# How do I write SEO friendly Images file names using ASP.NET Web Forms and Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, routes, seo

I would like improve SEO for my images on a website.

In my scenario:

- I have my file for an image inside a folder: `mysite.com/cdn/cms/images/15554.jpg` (15554 represent the Imageid)
- I would like rewrite the `src` attribute for this file name so it would looks like `mysite.com/cdn/cms/images/mypicturename-15554.jpg`

How can I accomplish this using only ASP.NET Routing features within .NET 4?

Comment: I would recommend setting up a route for your images and removing the need for the image extension all together. Something like `images/{id}/{name}` that way the engine always recognizes the name for the image source and your code can identify the image based on ID.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I see now your point. Now I have a friendly url for my image in mt browser code, but does not map to the physical path... how can I display this image? thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a handler for the image resource.  That way you can manage how you want to "virtually" name them however you want.  Then when an outside request comes in whether they are actually using the site or trying to link to the image through a request you can map the virtual name to the name on the file structure (or in the database depending on your setup).

A Handler is definitely the way you want to go.  Very low overhead.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code for the Handler or are you able to point me a good resource? Thanks on this

Comment: I have code... However, it is rather lengthy but you will be able to cut and paste.  Is there some way I can email it to you?

Comment: Hey GibboK.. Here is an excellent article (with code).  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomImageHandler.aspx